# how to pass the following pytest

Tags: python

I am trying to compute the first and second derivative of the following function and the pytest checks the error of my calculation.

I tried to change the value of h in order to pass the pytest yet I am unable to so.

```
def error_5_1_11(x):

    def f(x): return x ** 3 - 0.3 * x ** 2 - 8.56 * x + 8.448

    def f_1(f, x, h=10E-10):
        return (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2 * h)

    def f_2(f, x, h=10E-4):
        return (f(x + h) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - h)) / h ** 2

    return f_1(f, x)-(-8.56), f_2(f, x)-(-0.6)


import pytest
from error import *
from numpy import allclose, array
from numpy import allclose

def test_error():
    (a, b) = error_5_1_11(0)
    assert(abs(a) < 10E-13 and abs(b) < 10E-14)
```

what modification do I need to make in order to pass the following pytest, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix will be to add keywords arguments on your main function.

```py
def error_5_1_11(x, h1 = 10E-10, h2=10E-4): 
    def f(x):
         return x ** 3 - 0.3 * x ** 2 - 8.56 * x + 8.448 

     def f_1(f, x, h=h1): 
           return (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2 * h) 

     def f_2(f, x, h=h2): 
             return (f(x + h) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - h)) / h ** 2 

     return f_1(f, x)-(-8.56), f_2(f, x)-(-0.6) 

import pytest 
from error import * 
from numpy import allclose, array 

def test_error(): 
    (a, b) = error_5_1_11(0, h1=10E-13, h2=10E-14) 
    assert all(abs(a) < 10E-13 and abs(b) < 10E-14)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. It still failed the pytest.

Comment: @ZimingWang I have updated the code with `all` tell me if it's

Comment: That's another problem here, I shouldn't make any change to the test file. I am sorry I didn't mention it.